# Tableview with UiRefreshControl stuck after pull to refresh

Tags: ios, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

1. It works fine for the first 2-3 times but `UITableView` gets stuck when pulled for the 4th time.
2. Again when I touch the `UITableView` it starts working fine.[image]

Comment: Post your code what you have tried till now.

Comment: Are you fetching table data on main thread?

Comment: call `refreshControl.endRefreshing()` at appropriate point after you are done loading data for refreshed table view. Most appropriate point it to end refreshing in `numberOfSectionsInTableView(_:)` method. Please place your code for better assistance.

Comment: self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Fetching data..."];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(refreshActiveOrders)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.activeOrderTbl addSubview:self.refreshControl];

Comment: -(void)refreshActiveOrders{
    DisplayData *displayData =[[ DisplayData alloc]init];
    NSString *gmailID =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"email"];
    NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"token"];
    if (gmailID.length>0) {
        [ displayData  GetDisplayData:gmailID withFB:@"" withToken:token withVendor:@""];
    }  
}

Answer (score 1):

**1st.** On Attributes inspector of your Simulated Metrics, enable the Refreshing on `Table View Controller`.

[image: Attributes inspector]

**2st.** Erase your unneeded refresh codes.